# Is it possible to stream a YouTube video to a C++ application?

Tags: c++, video, youtube, stream, youtube-api

Is it possible to stream a YouTube video to a C++ application?

In particular, I am wondering whether YouTube provides an API for this besides extracting the stream from the URL like livestreamer does (http://docs.livestreamer.io/cli.html).

If extracting the stream from the URL is the only way to do this then does anyone know if that is against YouTube's terms of service?

My goal is to stream video to a C++ application without hosting it myself and render it with DirectX.

I am asking this here because youtube shut down their forums.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible (after all, your browser, which is a C++ application, does it!). I believe it's also against the ToS but I haven't checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is against the [Terms of Service](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms) (section 4, paragraph C).

> You agree not to access Content through any technology or means other
>   than the video playback pages of the Service itself, the Embeddable
>   Player, or other explicitly authorized means YouTube may designate.

There [doesn't appear to be any API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) through which videos can be retrieved – as of writing, you must use an iframe to access YouTube videos, unless you're on Android.